# Django Error After Changing/Reverting Views

Tags: django, django-views

I was changing some views earlier related to some geolocation (that failed) and upon restoring the previous views, I'm receiving this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /report/all/
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'profiles_profile_detail' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

What's odd is that the views I altered and restored had nothing to do with this view or template. The urls.py file was not touched at all. All other pages in the application are displaying normally. I can't figure out what the problem might be.

Views:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from myapp.report.models import Story, UserProfile
from myapp.report.forms import ProfileForm, StoryForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.gis.utils import GeoIP

def all_stories(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect("django.contrib.auth.views.login")
    all_stories = Story.objects.all().order_by("-date")

    return render_to_response("report/storyline.html",
                                {'stories': all_stories},
                                context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def story_detail(request, story_id):
    story = get_object_or_404(Story, id=story_id)
    return render_to_response('report/detail.html',
                            {'story': story},
                                context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@login_required
def submit_story(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        story_form = StoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if story_form.is_valid():
            new_story = story_form.save(commit=False)
            new_story.author = request.user
            new_story.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/report/all/")
    else: # GET request
        story_form = StoryForm()
    return render_to_response("report/report.html", {'form': story_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Forms (changed but restored; appear to be working):

```
from django import forms
from stentorian.report.models import UserProfile, Story
from django.contrib.gis.utils import GeoIP

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile

class StoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Story
        exclude = ('author',)
```

Template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block page_title %}Stentorian{% endblock %}
{% block headline %}Stentorian Storyline{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">

        <h2>Welcome <a href="{% url profiles_profile_detail user.username %}">{{ user.username }}</a></h2>
```

```
 <div class="accordion" id="story_accordion">
        {% for story in stories %}
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle story-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#story_accordion" href="#story_{{ story.id }}">
                         {{ story.title }} - {{ story.author.username }} - {{ story.date }}
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="story_{{ story.id }}" class="accordion-body collapse{% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %} in{% endif %}">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                        <!-- <h2><a href="{% url detail story.id %}">{{story.title}}</a></h2>-->
                        <span><a href="{% url profiles_profile_detail story.author %}">{{story.author}}</a> </span><br>

                        <span>{{story.topic}}</span><br>
                        <span>{{story.zip_code}}</span><br>

                        <span>{{story.date}}</span><br>

                        <p>{{story.copy}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <br>

        {% endfor %}
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

The error is coming up on the line:

```
{% for story in stories %}
```

If anyone can provide an idea of why this is happening, it would be most appreciated. Again, the url wasn't changed, which seems to be the chief reason for this error.

Comment: show your urls.py file pls...... error is on this line {% url profiles_profile_detail user.username %}

Comment: urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^all/', 'stentorian.report.views.all_stories', name='all'),
    url(r'^detail/(?P<story_id>\d*)$', 'stentorian.report.views.story_detail', name='detail'),
    url(r'^report/$', 'stentorian.report.views.submit_story', name='write_story'),
    url(r'^detail/(?P<story_id>\d*)/edit/$', 'stentorian.report.views.edit_story', name='edit_story') apologies for not formatting in code; cannot figure out how to do so im comments.

Comment: And from django-profiles app: urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^create/$',views.create_profile,name='profiles_create_profile'),
                       url(r'^edit/$',
                           views.edit_profile,
                           name='profiles_edit_profile'),
                       url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$',
                           views.profile_detail,
                           name='profiles_profile_detail'),
                       url(r'^$',
                           views.profile_list,
                           name='profiles_profile_list'),
                       )

Answer (score 0):

Seems like u r not getting user.username

Try with this.

```
 <h2>Welcome <a href="{% url profiles_profile_detail request.user.username %}">{{ request.user.username }}</a></h2>
```

Comment: Same error. Absolutely bizarre since this has been running with no problem thus far and wasn't touched.

Comment: see this page [django-profile](http://code.google.com/p/django-profiles/source/browse/trunk/profiles/urls.py) . have u included /profiles/ in your root URLConf  ?

Comment: Deleting that entire line from the template also brings the same error.

Comment: With that line deleted and /report/all: TemplateSyntaxError at /report/all/
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'profiles_profile_detail' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.   ----This is just bizarre.

Comment: And, yes, I have the "include" for profiles in the URLConf. All the other pages show up fine.

Comment: there are many profiles_profile_detail  in your template . try to apply above solution in all {% url profiles_profile_detail ... $} . i can see one in your for loop.

Comment: Try commenting all {% url ... because no reverse match is cause by this tag only.

Comment: Those won't comment out in Django templates.

Comment: Could the html file be corrupted?

Comment: no man.........may be coming from cache. try to empty tmp directory in your project root .

Comment: How do you do that? You're right, btw. I copied the file into a new html file and changed the url and I got the same error.